# How do I omit rows in a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, filter

I have a dataframe and the top row contains the names of my variables. The following two rows are other information about the variables (questions asked in the survey, answer form), and then the fourth row begins the actual data from respondents. I want to generate a simple scatterplot, but I don't know how to omit the second and third rows. I'm assuming I can do this with filter, but I can't quite figure it out. The code I have is giving me an error saying it doesn't recognize the row names I'm using. Can anyone help with an example? Thank you!

```
COVID_survey_data %>%
    filter(answer_form, respondent_id) %>%
    ggplot(aes(q063, q064)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: When you first import the data you may want to remove those unneeded lines from the csv file after you download from qualtrics or surveymonkey or wherever.  They'll always be getting in your way.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep some rows out, you can use [] and use the minus simbol "-" to specify which row to "exclude".
Using your example, if you don't need the first 3 rows in COVID_survey_data:

```
COVID_survey_data[-c(1:3),] %>%
    ggplot(aes(q063, q064)) + geom_point()
```

If you prefer the tidyverse way, you can use slice function

```
COVID_survey_data %>%
slice(-1:-3) %>% 
ggplot(aes(q063, q064)) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 3):

The dplyr::slice function can be helpful in this situation

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

head(mtcars) # first 6 rows
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0
#>                   gear carb
#> Mazda RX4            4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag        4    4
#> Datsun 710           4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive       3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout    3    2
#> Valiant              3    1
# Note the first two are Mazda RX
# assume you do not want these 2 rows in the dataset
dim(mtcars) # dimensions
#> [1] 32 11

slice(mtcars, 3:n()) # rows 3-32
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0
#> Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0
#> Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1
#> Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1
#> Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1
#> Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1
#> Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0
#> Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1
#> Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1
#> Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0
#> AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0
#> Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0
#> Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0
#> Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0
#> Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1
#>                     am gear carb
#> Datsun 710           1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive       0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout    0    3    2
#> Valiant              0    3    1
#> Duster 360           0    3    4
#> Merc 240D            0    4    2
#> Merc 230             0    4    2
#> Merc 280             0    4    4
#> Merc 280C            0    4    4
#> Merc 450SE           0    3    3
#> Merc 450SL           0    3    3
#> Merc 450SLC          0    3    3
#> Cadillac Fleetwood   0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental  0    3    4
#> Chrysler Imperial    0    3    4
#> Fiat 128             1    4    1
#> Honda Civic          1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla       1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona        0    3    1
#> Dodge Challenger     0    3    2
#> AMC Javelin          0    3    2
#> Camaro Z28           0    3    4
#> Pontiac Firebird     0    3    2
#> Fiat X1-9            1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2        1    5    2
#> Lotus Europa         1    5    2
#> Ford Pantera L       1    5    4
#> Ferrari Dino         1    5    6
#> Maserati Bora        1    5    8
#> Volvo 142E           1    4    2
slice(mtcars, 3:32) # rows 3-32
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0
#> Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0
#> Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1
#> Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1
#> Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1
#> Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1
#> Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0
#> Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1
#> Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1
#> Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0
#> AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0
#> Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0
#> Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0
#> Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0
#> Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1
#>                     am gear carb
#> Datsun 710           1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive       0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout    0    3    2
#> Valiant              0    3    1
#> Duster 360           0    3    4
#> Merc 240D            0    4    2
#> Merc 230             0    4    2
#> Merc 280             0    4    4
#> Merc 280C            0    4    4
#> Merc 450SE           0    3    3
#> Merc 450SL           0    3    3
#> Merc 450SLC          0    3    3
#> Cadillac Fleetwood   0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental  0    3    4
#> Chrysler Imperial    0    3    4
#> Fiat 128             1    4    1
#> Honda Civic          1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla       1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona        0    3    1
#> Dodge Challenger     0    3    2
#> AMC Javelin          0    3    2
#> Camaro Z28           0    3    4
#> Pontiac Firebird     0    3    2
#> Fiat X1-9            1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2        1    5    2
#> Lotus Europa         1    5    2
#> Ford Pantera L       1    5    4
#> Ferrari Dino         1    5    6
#> Maserati Bora        1    5    8
#> Volvo 142E           1    4    2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
COVID_survey_data <- COVID_survey_data[complete.cases(COVID_survey_data),]
```